# I'm trying to understand PHP_SELF vs ProcessForm.php in the Action field of a <form>

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I am new to developing PHP forms and currently trying to understand and learn how they are processed.  If I understand it correctly, there are two approaches to using the "Action" attribute.

Method A: Use a separate PHP file to process the form.  So in your first file (Form.php), you have the code for the form and submit button.  Then in the ProcessForm.php file, you put all of your code for validating the data.  In this case, you define the form as

```
<form  method="post" action="ProcessForm.php" >
```

Method B: Use one PHP file for everything, including the code for the form, submit button, and all validation stuff (including output of error messages if form fields aren't entered properly).  Here, you define the the form as

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Right now, I don't understand if one of these methods is more correct or why you would use one vs the other.

I see a form as having four components: HTML for the form, PHP for connecting to MySQL, PHP for input validation/cleaning/error printout, and PHP for moving the data into the MySQL database.  I want my form to be able to (upon submitting) work as follows:

1. If there are one or more errors in the submission process, stay on the same page (stop the submit process) and display relevant error messages, with the fields all still populated (as opposed to blank).
2. If there are no errors in the submission process, move the data into MySQL, and then display a blank page that says "your data has been submitted successfully" and a link back to my homepage.

Currently I am using Method B, and have implemented #1 above successfully.  But I haven't achieved #2. So after this long story, my question is this:  Where am I supposed to put those four components?  In one file or two, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither method is "more correct"; both are just as valid, the one you choose completely depends on the UX you are trying to achieve. Where you are supposed to put the four components depends on whether you are using method A or B.

### For method A

If the form is on one page, and you're going to be submitting the data to another page via the `action="example.php"` attribute, the HTML for the form should (obviously) be on the first page, while everything else should be on the second (`example.php`) page (all the PHP and SQL). If there's a validation error, you can use `header(Location: firstpage.php?error=something)` to return users to the original page to fix their mistake.

### For method B

If you're doing everything on one page (by putting `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"` or simply `action=""`, both of which do the exact same thing), you should do the validation when a user submits the form on that one page, and if there are no validation errors, insert the data into the database and redirect the user using PHP's `header()` function.

---

As you're using method B, this is my more detailed step-by-step process of how I would handle such a form. In the example, `firstpage.php` is the page a user starts on, and `secondpage.php` is the page a user is taken to if all the information is correct.

1. Present the user with your form.
2. When a user submits the form, the data is submitted via POST or GET (depending on whether you want this information accessible via the URL. If you're not sure, use POST) to `firstpage.php` where the following PHP is:

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
  // Some validation function
  if (do_validation()) {
    // Information is valid, insert into db
    header(Location: secondpage.php);
    die();
  }
  else {
    echo "Error; the information you submitted is not valid.";
  }
}
?>
```

3. When the user ends up on `secondpage.php`, you can tell them that the form was successfully submitted.

Comment: I am using method B at the moment.  In that case, where/when would it make sense to echo the "your data has been submitted successfully" statement?  Somewhere on the form page or on the home page I redirect to?  (Not sure if this is a matter of preference or if there's a more sound method)

Comment: It should be on the page you're redirecting to; that's where users are taken when validation is successful and their data has been recorded in the database.

Comment: Does using the header() function in this way require output buffering?  I thought you can't do a redirect if you've already used a header on your page. My knowledge on this particular topic is almost zero.

Comment: As detailed in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), the `header()` function has two requirements: That you use the function before any output, meaning that you must put the PHP at the top of your page, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and that you use `die()` to prevent the rest of the script from running, which `header()` alone doesn't actually do. But if you do those two things, you shouldn't run into any problems using `header()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to the script that generates the form itself then you don't even need an action. So method 3 is:

```
<form method="post">
```

which is the best version since it will not break and makes it clear that one script renders and handles the post for the form.

Neither of your other methods is *ideal*. Really you should be looking at (Smarty or something similar) to let you template the HTML and separate the display from the logic. Having said that both options 1 & 2 are perfectly acceptable - if you choose not to use the (superior) option 3 from above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to a "Best Practice", but of the 4 "Components" you mentioned, I think a missing key item is client-side validation as well (javascript typically). This saves you the "round trip" overhead of processing a form that could have already been validated before submitting to the server to handle.

With that being said (and because it's the approach I use), you'll be incorporating some javascript, so what I do is use javascript to validate my fields "on submit" (I override the form's default submit with a javascript event handler), then, if it validates, perform the submit. I do this with ajax, or you can use standard javascript to submit the form. You can even use javascript to set the "action" attribute dynamically (assuming you need to - see @Paul's reasoning why you may not need to).

The php file it submits to typically does 0 presentation work. It connects to the database, saves the "post'ed" info, closes the connection, and returns a status (which is typically why I like ajax because it's easier for me to handle that status response). Based on the status response, you can display an error message (like an alert, a bootstrap modal or info alert, etc.) or a success message/redirect.

While my answer does not offer code, I think the methodology above will serve you better based on your question. The "how" is the easy part once you understand the steps you want to take.

Comment: This is interesting information, though I think it's a bit out of range of my skill level.  My knowledge of JS is limited to what I learned from Khan Academy's JS courses, and I haven't learned any Ajax yet.

Comment: It's actually VERY basic stuff you could learn in a night or two (W3 Schools is a great site with examples). Why I think this is the best method is you'll have people posting methods for "POST'ing" to a separate PHP file, but if there's errors, you'll have to return to the previous form page. Guess what? All that user's hard work entering the form data is lost! User's love that! Especially on long forms, or ones with large textarea type fields. Can it be "reloaded"? Sure... but the amount of code to do that.. might as well do it with JS the first time! :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have been using the W3 Schools tutorial to do all of this (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp).  I've already set up my page using their methodology to return error messages for individual fields (since all of the fields on my form are required).